# how to integrate MOIP payment gateway from c# application?

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I am trying to integrate payment system MOIP from my c# web service for iphone app purchase.

I go through [this link](http://labs.moip.com.br/) but not getting if it is neccessary to create account at MOIP site for payee?

What are the complete steps?
I want to implement for pre-paid payment.
Any tutorial with steps will be helpful.